# The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I try to do SQL-1999 style recursion in SQL Server

```
 CREATE TABLE addressparts(
    AddrPartId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    AddrPartTypeId VARCHAR(30),
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    constraint PK_OBJECTS primary key (AddrPartId))

insert into addressparts values (1, 0, 'country','Zimbabwe');
insert into addressparts values (2, 1, 'city','zi');
insert into addressparts values (3, 2, 'subcity','kalkli');
insert into addressparts values (4, 2, 'subcity','kalkli1');
```

I want select recursive query

```
WITH 
 Rec (AddrPartId, ParentID, AddrPartTypeId, name)
 AS (
   SELECT AddrPartId, ParentID, AddrPartTypeId, name FROM addressparts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Rec.AddrPartId, Rec.ParentID, rec.AddrPartTypeId, Rec.name
    FROM Rec
    inner join addressparts on Rec.AddrPartId = addressparts.ParentID
   )
 SELECT * FROM Rec 
 WHERE ParentID=0;
```

But I have error like in title

I want expected result as

```
AddrPartId ParentID
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 2
```

by level

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: No. I have table ParentID=0 and 100 tables with same AddrPartId

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: I trying select id and all parent id

Comment: @ifooi - Post the expected result in question. Your query has logical mistakes as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Recursive CTE will do 100 recursion.

Add option max recursion at the end of cte to increase the default recursion. But there are logical mistakes are there as well in your query. If am not wrong you are looking for something like this

```
;WITH Rec (AddrPartId, ParentID, AddrPartTypeId, NAME)
     AS (SELECT AddrPartId,
                ParentID,
                AddrPartTypeId,
                NAME
         FROM   addressparts
         WHERE  ParentID = 0 -- add the parent id filter here 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT A.AddrPartId,  -- don't select from recursive cte 
                A.ParentID,
                A.AddrPartTypeId,
                A.NAME
         FROM   Rec
                INNER JOIN addressparts A
                        ON Rec.AddrPartId = A.ParentID)
SELECT *
FROM   Rec
OPTION (maxrecursion 0); -- here
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/WFSI7618)

Comment: no, this is not problem solving. it is just restrcition

Comment: you right, logical mistaces, I want select like level in oracle

Comment: @ifooi - It just gives the same result as you posted in question. Added demo as well check it out

Comment: -- OPTION (maxrecursion 0); -- here